# if the universe is flat does it mean it exists only in our mind as math?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, cosmology, astronomy, energy-conservation

> My dad, who is a retired mathematician, has this attitude, which I
>   think we all have as kids, that ultimately reality is made of stuff.
>   End of story. If you look around yourself in the world, you don’t see
>   anything that’s mathematical, right? But physicists have discovered
>   that all this stuff is made out of elementary particles, like quarks
>   and electrons. What properties does an electron actually have? It has
>   the properties -1, ½, and 1. These are properties that we physicists
>   have made up geeky names for, like electric charge and spin and lepton
>   number. But they’re just numbers! They’re just mathematical
>   properties!
>
> So all these building blocks of nature, these particles, actually have
>   no properties at all, except for mathematical properties. So in that
>   sense, they are purely mathematical objects. Classic materialism is
>   dead: “stuff” isn’t the end of the story.
>
> And the same deal with the fabric of what’s around us, space itself.
>   It has the property three, the number of dimensions. That’s a number.
>   That’s a mathematical property. All this space and the stuff in space
>   is purely mathematical with only mathematical properties.

Max Tegmark - cosmologist.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: my question is very clear. in my view flat means two dimensions. is there anything two dimensional which exists?

Comment: In that case the question is based on a misconception.

Comment: misconception? or that i want to know what is meant by flat? can you give me an example of a flat object?

Comment: Again, the adjective "flat" as used above does not apply to objects, rather it is a property of space-time. Indeed as used above it also applies only on the largest scales in the universe (Dr. Krauss doesn't care that space-time in the vicinity of the Earth's surface is slightly curves as long as the universe as a whole exhibits vanishingly little curvature).

Comment: is it the same idea quantum mechanics doesnt apply to macro objects when in truth the macro is made of micro particles-waves?

Comment: "Flat" is used as in "Euclidean Geometry". In other words, there is one and only one line through a point that is parallel to another line. In curved universes you can have none (spherical geometry) or more than one (hyperbolic geometry).

Comment: if flat implies more than 2D then a cube is flat. if space is part of the universe then beyond the limits of the universe there is no space, or space is infinite and objects contained in it give form to the universe? no objects no universe. and arent objects spacial in themselves?

Comment: i think the universe is given form by the structure of our brain-mind. the universe without being measured is not a universe . all our thoughts about the universe, our maths about it, our measurements are rules, laws of our own brain, the universe is inside the skull.

Comment: The `Flat` word is a geometric definition ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_(geometry) ), you're mixing common-sense meaning with rigorous mathematical definitions (however common sense helps in understanding).

Comment: maths are in the brain, as abstractions in measurements. outside the brain there is not any maths.

Answer (score 9):

> If the universe is flat does it mean it doesn't exist?

What kind of incoherent question is this?

"If the universe is flat" presumes the universe exists and is spatially flat.

Your question amounts to "Does the *existence* of a spatially flat universe mean the *non-existence* of a spatially flat universe?".

Isn't the answer analytically *no*?

Comment: Exactly: In a(ny) reasonable logical system $A\wedge \neg A =$ false, regardless of the content of the statement $A$.

Comment: @Danu This is not logical "and", it is implication.

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not. It exists wether it's flat or not, and I don't see how any of what you quote is relevant.

Comment: doesnt flat means 2 dimensions? give an example of a two dimension object which exists? i dont know any. only mental images, which are illusions.

Comment: The quote is not relevant . is your answer relevant? why?

Comment: @felino: an example other than the universe you mean right?

Comment: @felino "Flat" does not mean two-dimensional it means that any two coplanar, parallel lines are everywhere the same distance apart. It is roughly equivalent to Euclid's fifth postulate, and in General Relativity that represents a special case that need not be so.

Comment: an example of a flat object, please.

Comment: if the universe is flat all we see and experience is flat . we cant exclude ourselves from the universe, are you flat? if all we perceive is flat then its all a dream, without a dreamer, just virtual universe.

Comment: @felino, around these parts, a *flat* universe means a universe with zero (3D) spatial curvature.  Evidently, in your neck of the woods, a 'flat' universe is a 2D flatland?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatland